# Subset vs left_join in R to filter a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a general query. I am using two different ways to subset my dataframe in R. And to my surprise, i am getting different number of samples by both ways although it shouldnot be like this as the input data is same. CAN some one please explain me the logic behind this.

Method:1

```
Male<- ph_table[(ph_table$Sex == "M"), ]
MaleID<-unique(Male$ID)
MaleID<-as.data.frame(MaleID)
colnames(MaleID)[1] <- "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
Male_maf<-left_join(MaleID,Big_data, by="Tumor_Sample_Barcode")
dim(Male_maf)
[1] 1983  133
```

Method_2

```
colnames(ph_table)[which(names(ph_table) == "ID")]<- "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
Male_samples<-unique(subset(ph_table,Sex=="M")$Tumor_Sample_Barcode)
M_maf<-subset(Big_data,Tumor_Sample_Barcode %in% Male_samples)
dim(M_maf)
[1] 1885  133
```

Does it make any sense?

Comment: I don't see a reason they should be different. I'd suggest looking at some of the rows that are in Method 1 but not in Method 2. If you could do that, and then share 10-20 rows of sample input *including some of those rows missing in Method 2* then we can try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You can find the extra rows with `extra_rows = setdiff(Male_maf, M_maf)`. Also, when you share sample data we certainly don't need all 133 columns. Include only the relevant columns, something like `dput(Big_data[1:5, c("Tumor_Sample_Barcode", "Some_other_big_data_column")])` to give a copy/pasteable sample of the first 5 rows including only a couple columns. Choose rows to illustrate the issue as I mention in my previous comment, and if there is a unique ID column in `Big_data` that would be a useful other column to include.

Comment: One difference may be if there are IDs in `ph_table` that are not in `Big_data`.  Method 1 will keep them (with all the other columns having `NA` values) and Method 2 will drop them. You could fix this by using `inner_join` instead of `left_join` in method 1.

Comment: (And if you're interested in a full `dplyr` re-write of Method 1, you can try `ph_table %>% filter(Sex == "M") %>% distinct(Tumor_Sample_Barcode = ID) %>% left_join(Big_data)` which seems a little cleaner)

Comment: Ok so by using method1 with  inner_join  , No i am getting the same samples as of M_maf. 
[1] 1885  133

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @GregorThomas . It has been very informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `left_join(MaleID,Big_data, by="Tumor_Sample_Barcode")` keep all rows of `MaleID` whether or not they have matches in `Big_data`.

`subset(Big_data,Tumor_Sample_Barcode %in% Male_samples)` on the other hand will only keep `Tumor_Sample_Barcode` values that occur in both.

If you use `inner_join` instead of `left_join` they will be equivalent.